# How many decimals the `step` and `min` attributes can have on an html number input?

Tags: html, forms, browser, decimal

Designing a form with an input as a number, from its standard (namely : a default Ethereum ERC20 token) it can have up to 18 decimals (sometimes more for non default tokens). The html element to input it would turn like :

```html
<input name="amount" type="number" min="0.000000000000000001" step="0.000000000000000001" />
```

It looks like this attributes are too low for the browser I'm using to take them into account and it disables the stepping features altogether (the up and down arrows are not reactive).

Through trial and errors on https://jsfiddle.net/g68t30o5/ I was able to determine it works as expected with 16 decimals (`0.0000000000000001`) for the Firefox browser.

I'm then wondering if this is a standard limit (nothing about it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step) and/or if it happens to be different on various browsers ?

Comment: Chrome allows only 6 decimal points. I don't believe it's has anything to do with attribute limitation, but rather floating point in javascript itself. Just type in devtools console: `0.0001` and start adding zeros to see how many it allows.

Comment: @vanowm might be it for chrome. But for Firefox I can type 50 `0` in the console and it still outputs a consistent result : `1e-50`